# Autofill foreign key field based on the slug in the URL

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a forum website where the user selects the game that they want to post about and writes the post. The problem is I don't want the user to select the game from the drop-down foreign key field. I want the foreign key field to populate itself based on the slug provided in the URL.

**models.py posts app**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    # need this field automatically filled out
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name="posts",null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "posts:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk,
                "slug": self.game.slug,
            }
        )
```

**models.py games app**

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("games:single", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

**urls.py posts app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name="all"),
    # need this slug to match the game
    path("new/<slug>/", views.CreatePost.as_view(), name="create"),
]
```

**views.py posts app**

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('title','message','game')
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user', 'game')
```

I'm guessing I need to grab the game object with the same slug as the one provided in the url?

Comment: answered based on slug. If the id is known, then it is easier to get the desired record through it.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following from the slug:game_slug parameter, it turns out the slug by which I get the record from Game (id). By this id, a record from Post is obtained. Some data is displayed on the page. Please note that get is used, the required entry must be one.

views.py

```
def game(request, game_slug):
    pos = Game.objects.get(slug=game_slug).id
    aaa = Post.objects.get(game_id=pos)

    return HttpResponse(f"""
            <p>title: {aaa.title}</p>
            <p>user: {aaa.user}</p>
            <p>created_at: {aaa.created_at}</p>
        """)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/<slug:game_slug>/', game, name='game'),
]
```

Post data looks like this:
[image]
Game:
[image]
In my case, I went to:

http://localhost:8000/new/sport/

And got the following data:

```
post3

user: Tom

created_at: 2022-10-04 14:48:49.576413+00:00
```